# Trying to submit form data using JQuery results in empty Reqest.Files inside C#

Tags: c#, jquery, forms, file, submit

HTML:

```
<form action="~/BlogPost/UploadHomeReport" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload-image-form">
       <input type="file" id="image-upload" />
 </form>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).on("change", "#image-upload", function(e) {
    $("#upload-image-form").submit();
}
```

Controller:

```
 public JsonResult UploadHomeReport()
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (string upload in Request.Files)
            {
                if (Request.Files[0] != null)
                {

                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(upload);
                    MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
                    Request.Files[0].InputStream.CopyTo(target);
                    byte[] data = target.ToArray();
                    var path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Images/" + fileName);
                    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                    {
                        client.UploadData(path, data);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            return Json("Upload failed");
        }

        return Json("File uploaded successfully");
    }
```

Why does Request.Files become an empty file?
[image]

I have done this before and then it works but i just can't get it to work now.